# Why can't c++ ifstreams read from devices?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, fstream

I knew I should never have started using c++ io, the whole "type safety" argument is a red herring (does anyone *really* find that it's one of their most pressing problems?). Anyhow, I did, and discovered a strange difference between ifstreams and FILE*s and plain old file descriptors: ifstreams cannot read from a device. Can anyone think of a reason why?

```
const char* path = "/dev/disk3";
char        b;

// this works
FILE* f= fopen(path, "rb");
int i = fread(&b, 1, 1, f);     // returns 1, success!

// this does not work
ifstream    cf(path, ios::binary);
cf.read(&b, 1);
bool        good = cf.good();   // returns false, failure.
```

Comment: FWIW, I think your off-topic "big fat lie" comment might prevent knowledgeable people from answering this question.

Comment: OS and compiler versions might help...

Comment: I agree with Kristopher Johnson. I don't know the answer, but I know I won't feel compelled to search for it.

Comment: Ok, maybe "big fat lie" is slightly too emotional. Let's see if I can change that.

OS is leopard 10.5.5, gcc vers = 4.0.1

Comment: I've got a fairly good idea. But I don't like this kind of baiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device is unbuffered and must be read from in 512 byte multiples. ifstream does it's own buffering and strangely decided to read *1023* bytes ahead, which fails with "Invalid argument". Interestingly, this ifstream is implemented on top of a FILE*. However, FILE* left to its own devices was reading ahead using a nicer, rounder number of bytes.

Thanks to dtrace for vital clues. I guess we'll never know if the folk who thought they knew  answer but didn't want to say were right.

Comment: So, in other words, the `FILE*` version was only working by accident because of the underlying choice of buffer size. If you can control the buffer size for a C++ stream, then it would probably work just as well. The `basic_filebuf::setbuf` function looks like it might be relevant.

Comment: Exactly right, FILE* only worked through sheer luck, so I dropped down to the file descriptor interface. Not before ripping out all the iostream code, though. I don't miss it. Hope that's not too inflammatory for SO-09! Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me, its not a problem inherent to c++ stream file I/O as you seem to think.

Maybe try adding `ios::in` to the openmode flags. According to 27.8.1.6 of the standard, it is required to or with ios::in so this probably won't do anything.

Try checking which bit is actually set - instead of calling good(), try checking bad(), eof(), and fail() individually. This might give a clue as to what the error was.

Comment: Works in your implementation and not in mine = non portable. 
I "downgraded" to FILE* and everything's working fine.
Adios c++ streams, can't say it's been nice knowing you.

Comment: Afterwards, the flags are
good = 0
eof = 0
fail = 1

AND... perror says "Invalid argument".
I wonder why.

Comment: Getting interesting, no? Almost as much fun as "Kon and Bal".

Answer (score 0):

I have found random issues like this in C++ I/O for years.  It has always seemed like a backwards step to me.

I haven't tried it, but you might want to look at what Boost has to offer:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html